# create a channel through node js in hyperledger fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

the channel is supposed to be created with the `peer channel create` inside the container after generating the channel tx files with  configtxgen.
I wanted to know if it is possible to create the channel tx files and create the channel with the help of the node js server like previously in the fabric 1.4 we used to do with the help of the fabric-client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there isn't an API in the Node SDK (v2) to manage the chaincode lifecycle.
You should be able to use the SDK to invoke lifecycle functions using the system '_lifecycle' chaincode.
There are also third-party libraries built on the SDK which provides some lifecycle support, e.g https://github.com/davidkhala/fabric-common/tree/master/nodejs/admin

Comment: thank you for the information will look into the link you have provided.